# Python : Use a WITH (context manager) from an other function

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

I would like to use a with statement from an other function
unfortunately if I yield the value it's considered a generator and I can't use it as a context manager in the calling function

```py
class Something:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

    def do_something(self):
        pass

    def do_something_else(self):
        pass


def inner_context_manager():
    with Something() as a:
        a.do_something()
        yield a


def test_inner_context_manager():
    with inner_context_manager() as b:  # NOT WORKING -> AttributeError: __enter__
        b.do_something_else()

    for b in inner_context_manager():  # WORKING
        b.do_something_else()
```

Comment: Did you mean to use the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator? You look like you've mimicked code that uses the decorator, but without the decorator.

Comment: Thank you , that is perfect , I'm updating the answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a other object exposing **enter** , like this :

```py
def inner_context_manager():
    class Wrapper(Something):
        def __enter__(self):
            tmp = super(Wrapper, self).__enter__()
            tmp.do_something()
            return tmp

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            super(Wrapper, self).__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    return Wrapper()


def test_user_inner_context_manager():
    with inner_context_manager() as b:
        b.do_something_else()
```

or just add the decorator [contextlib.contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```py
@contextmanager
def inner_context_manager():
    with Something() as a:
        a.do_something()
        yield a

def test_user_inner_context_manager():
    with inner_context_manager() as b:
        b.do_something_else()
```